# Java/Android Custumised MP3 Player : how to set landmarks in a MP3 Player

Tags: java, android, mp3

The main idea is to have an App that can read an mp3 with looping option in this way:
For example, my mp3 of 3min have 3 parts, I want to iterate this mp3 like:
Part 1: 3 times, Part 2: 3 times, Part 1 & 2: 3 times and so one so forth...

My need is to know how can I add landmarks? should I use metadata and set tags like : [PART_1: 00:30:00, PART_2: .....] ?
How can I loop from those landmarks?

Thank you,